# File not found when registering DLL with TFileRun and regsvr32

Tags: delphi, regsvr32

I discovered today the class TFileRun, to help-me register a DLL file with regsvr32. My code is like this:

```
procedure TForm1.RegisterBHO;
var
  Exec: TFileRun;
begin
  DestDir:= PChar(GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA') + '\Java Update');
  Exec:= TFileRun.Create(Self);
  Exec.FileName:= 'regsvr32';
  Exec.Parameters:= DestDir + '\JavaUpdate.dll';
  Exec.Operation:= 'open';
  Exec.Execute;
  Exec.Free;
end;
```

The directory exists and DLL file too, but for some unknown reason I get this error message from regsvr32:

[image]

Looks like it's getting only a part of the dir name... Why that's happening?!

Comment: please, add the tag specifying delphi version. When dealing with DLLs and strings that might be crucial info. There is "delphi" tag but there are also tags for every delphi version out there. Please, put both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:
`Exec.Parameters:= '"'+DestDir + '\JavaUpdate.dll"';`

Answer (score 9):

The `\Java Update` folder contains spaces, so you have to quote the entire directory path:

```
DestDir:= GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA') + '\Java Update';
Exec:= TFileRun.Create(Self);
Exec.FileName:= 'regsvr32';
Exec.Parameters:= '"' + DestDir + '\JavaUpdate.dll' + '"';
```

As another answer mentions, it's probably better to do the registration yourself in your code, though. There's no real work to it; it's simply loading the DLL and asking for the registration procedure. Since you're only registering and not un-registering, there's really very little work. Here's an example (reworked from old Borland demo code):

```
type
  TRegProc = function : HResult; stdcall;

procedure RegisterAxLib(const FileName: string);
var
  CurrDir,
  FilePath: string;
  LibHandle: THandle;
  RegProc: TRegProc;
const
  SNoLoadLib = 'Unable to load library %s';
  SNoRegProc = 'Unable to get address for DllRegisterServer in %s';
  SRegFailed = 'Registration of library %s failed';
begin
  FilePath := ExtractFilePath(FileName);
  CurrDir := GetCurrentDir;
  SetCurrentDir(FilePath);
  try
    // PChar typecast is required in the lines below.
    LibHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(FileName));
    if LibHandle = 0 then 
      raise Exception.CreateFmt(SNoLoadLib, [FileName]);
    try
      @RegProc := GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'DllRegisterServer');
      if @RegProc = nil then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(SNoRegProc, [FileName]);
      if RegProc <> 0 then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt(SRegFailed, [FileName]);
    finally
      FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
    end;
  finally
    SetCurrentDir(CurrDir);
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this - you won't need to worry about the double quotes when doing it using `LoadLibrary`:

```
var
  sFile: string;
begin
  sFile := GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA') + '\Java Update' +
             '\JavaUpdate.dll';

  RegisterAxLib(sFile);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but result is same as first, so I accepted first as solution.

Comment: @HwTrap It's more important to accept the best answer rather than the first answer. +1 to Ken. ken took the time to explain in words. That's very valuable in my view.

Comment: @HwTrap remove PChar typecasting altogether. There is no sense in using C-String in pure Delphi code. Just slows the program and makes it fragile (future changes can easily introduce crashes).
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtActns.TFileRun - no place for PChar there.   Ah, koay, now i have at last >6 chars to proceed with editing  :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The You can make that edit. Please, I encourage you to simply correct such mistakes yourself.

Comment: I got the edit. :-) Thanks for the catch. The PChar wasn't needed, but it doesn't "slow the program" if you're doing a straight string to PChar (there are no type conversions or anything - the typecast just tells the compiler to use it as a null-terminated pointer to character, which is usually required for API calls if you're concatenating Delphi strings). There's no performance involved, and little risk of future "crashes" because of it.

Comment: initially i just added closing parenthesis. the SO told me 6 chars minimum allowed edit. Frankly, on programmers Q&A site, where each symbol may change the program logic or compilability - that is rather strange limitation. Maybe it is protection against malevolent hard to spot changes, dunno. As long as i saw more letters to change - i made the edit. Now u may review it :-)

Comment: You're talking about a single string that immediate gets released again when it goes out of scope. While technically it's a *very, very* minor point, it's also case of premature optimization to worry much about it. You're right; I assumed when I first answered that the poster had a reason for the typecast, and didn't check that for correctness. I was more concerned with providing an answer to the question asked than in reviewing the code for other issues. I've now removed it, so I don't see any need for further discussion of the issue. :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The, when you edit someone's post, please don't insert your own personal opinions or comments. Posts should be edited to improve content or fix code errors, not voice your own feelings. And there are no unbalanced parentheses; I fixed those half an hour ago.

Comment: @KenWhite - well, few minutes ago i saw one of those still present, even if typecast and 2nd of them was removed. But anyway, too much on this topic :-)

Comment: No need for double quotes when calling LoadLibrary. Don't like the change to working dir. Why would that be a good idea?

Comment: @David, I didn't think the double-quotes were needed; just thought I'd mention just in case. As I said, the code originally came from a Borland demo (it's actually still in D2007, in the ActiveX\TRegSvr folder), so you'd have to ask them why they felt it was necessary to change folders. :-) I just modified it for use in an app once, and quickly modified that code to post here for addition to my answer. You're right, though; now that I look at the code again, it's not necessary. I'll get rid of it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Working dir is probably set because DLL may require other DLLs to be loaded. So it is just heuristics 'if there are secondary DLLs let's hope they are in the same folder". It all could be replaced with a call to LoadLibraryEx with alternate search path. But probably Borland/Emb just do not know about that function :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: You're probably right about dependencies being the reason for the directory change. I think I'll revert and put those back in for that reason. As far as `LoadLibraryEx`, I don't think it existed back in the Win95 days when Borland added that sample code to Delphi 3. :-)

Comment: If a COM DLL has dependencies that require the working dir to be modified at load time, then that COM DLL cannot work. CoCreateInstance won't change the working dir and so it will fail. So that code must be pointless. I'll bet you won't find anything like that in the source code for regsvr32 which is available.

Comment: @David: No, that's not it. It needs to find the dependencies at **registration** time, so the DLL can be loaded to register. Once that's done (and Windows knows where it and the dependencies are located from the registry), the dir change isn't needed any longer. But OK, you don't like the folder change. It can't hurt anything (it's properly protected by a try..finally, and will execute extremely rapidly, and requires two extra string vars); what's the harm in leaving it in there? And if you decide to use the code for something, feel free to remove it before you do so. :-)

Comment: Dependencies are resolved at module load time, ever time a module is loaded, by the loader. So you've got that mixed up. Changing working dir affects entire process, all threads. Not to be taken lightly.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think it really matters.

Comment: @David, I think you're over-thinking this. :-) You're forgetting the context it's happening it - registering an ActiveX control. How frequently are you going to to that at a point in time you need to worry about a change of dir affecting entire processes and all threads? It's a rare occurrence to register COM libraries, and usually it's for an installation or update. But you're right: as a general rule I don't think changing working dir is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably making too much of this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan while those functions were introduced for COM, they are per se a handy convention and can be used outside COM realm.

Comment: @KenWhite 'I don't think it existed back in the Win95 days' that's true, but there is also SafeLoadLibrary function, and it could be updated. It's scope of use is much wider than COM-like registrations.

Comment: @Arioch'The: I'm not sure SafeLoadLibrary existed when that demo was written, and it does more than just register AX controls. It doesn't matter, though, so I don't know why you keep wanting to discuss it. The actual question asked was "why doesn't my code work?" which was answered; the "do it yourself" code was added as extra bonus material. The function as written works fine. Please remember SO isn't designed to be a chat room. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Truly, launching external exe just to call one function seems a bit overkill.

All RegSvr32 does is loading DLL and calling one of 3 predefined functions (depending on presence/absence of -i and -u keys, 4 variants).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759846.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691457.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162.aspx

This all you can do from your application - in much more reliable way. What if on some system you would not have regsvr32.exe in path for example ?

Sketch about like that, you'd adapt it to your application and your version of Delphi:

```
  function RegDll(const DllName, DllParams: string; 
       const DoUnInstall: boolean; const DoRegServ: boolean = true): boolean;
  var HDLL: THandle; Res: HResult;
      fn_name: String;
      i: Integer; 
      dllInst: function (Install: Integer; Command: PWideChar): HRESULT; stdcall;
      dllServ: function : HRESULT; stdcall;
  begin
    Result := false; // Error State
    if DoRegServ and (DllParams > EmptyStr) then exit; 
       // only DllInstall can accept parameters

    HDLL := SafeLoadLibrary(DllName);

    // if HDll = 0 then RaiseLastWin32Error;
    if HDLL <> 0 then try

       if DoRegServ then begin

          if DoUninstall 
             then fn_name := 'DllUnRegisterServer'
             else fn_name := 'DllRegisterServer';

          dllServ := GetProcAddress(HDLL, PChar(fn_name));

          // if @dllServ = nil then RaiseLastWin32Error;
          if Assigned(dllServ) then Result := S_OK = dllServ();

       end else begin             
          dllInst := GetProcAddress(HDLL, PChar('DllInstall'));

          // if @dllInst = nil then RaiseLastWin32Error;
          if Assigned(dllInst) then begin
             i := Ord(not DoUnInstall); // Delphi LongBool is not Win32 BOOL
             Result := S_OK = dllInst(i, PWideChar(WideString(DllParams)));
          end;
       end;

    finally
       FreeLibrary(HDLL);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: System without regsvr32 is a broken system. No point planning for that eventuality. That said, it can be cleaner to do such registration in proc so this is a good answer. +1

Comment: Another thought. One advantage of out-of-proc reg is that it allows you to elevate if the calling app runs as limited user

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, it does, hypothetically, if you would do it. But the code in question does not requests elevation, does not analyze OS and user grants, if elevation might be required or not. So it is not the question here. More practical reason to me would be memory isolation, if DLL appears broken (but then how to use it?). But i look at original code and see there potential unguarded memory leak, no errors checking (my sketch is deleting error details, but at least it tries to preserve the very fact of error). So, i thought at last - that would be too much details for this question :-)

Comment: Indeed. I offered the comment as an addendum to your answer.

Comment: I'd upvote this (because it is a better way to register a DLL), but it doesn't answer the question asked, which was why the code being used didn't work.

Comment: @KenWhite: I'd upvote it anyway. Just like specifications, many questions on SO don't ask about the real problem, but about a solution to that problem which may or may not be the best solution to the real problem. If someone offers an alternative solution to what may be the underlying problem then that has value in and of itself. I know I often find little gems in these alternative answers and try to "reward" their appearance by upvoting them. While this answer may not directly help OP, it certainly is of value for other people when searching SO on this topic.